# How to embed an attribute in a DataRow?

Tags: c#

I am doing my project, in which I have a database of books. I have loaded that database in DataTable "Books". There is another DataTable "Watermark_books", which contains all attribute as "Books" datatable has, as well as an extra attribute which is watermark of each row. 
I have to calculated watermark, now I have to embed that watermark attribute in "Watermark_books" datatable.

Kindly have a look on code which i have written.

```
int ky= 0;

double attrib = CalculateWatermarkAttribute(i, j, out ky);

DataRow dataRow = dataSet.Tables["Watermark_Books"].NewRow();

DataRow tmpRow = dataSet.Tables["Books"].Select("id=" + ky)[0];

dataRow.ItemArray = tmpRow.ItemArray; // this copies all columns of one row to new row

dataRow.ItemArray[7] = attrib; // this line of code is not working

dataSet.Tables["Watermark_Books"].Rows.Add(dataRow);
```

Can anyone point out what is wrong with above mentioned line of code....

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What is the exception you are getting on that line?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Post the error details.

Comment: Code is not generating any exception or error that is why i could not figure out the problem..

Comment: "this line of code is not working" Explain full exception message, please.

Comment: actually this line is not storing attrib in 7th index of dataRow.ItemArray, without giving any error compiler goes on..

Comment: Your `ky` variable has an intial value of 0 (zero). Are you sure that a row with ID=0 exist in the "Books" table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
        int ky= 0;
        double attrib = CalculateWatermarkAttribute(i, j, out ky);
        DataRow dataRow = dataSet.Tables["Watermark_Books"].NewRow();
        DataRow tmpRow = dataSet.Tables["Books"].Select("id=" + ky)[0];

        foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in dataSet.Tables["Watermark_Books"].Columns)
        {
            if (column.ColumnName == "WatermarkColumn")
                dataRow["WatermarkColumn"] = attrib;
            else
                dataRow[column.ColumnName] = tmpRow[column.ColumnName];
        }
```

Comment: @AsadHanif take a look [How does accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?